# Driver: San Francisco - Which cars unlock challenges?

Tags: driver-san-francisco

In Driver: San Francisco I bought the DeLorean and drove it at 88mph. This unlocked the "Blast From The Past" challenge (the garage level from the first Driver game).

Do any other cars unlock challenges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having now completed the game, I can answer this.

The DeLorean is the only car that unlocks a challenge. There is one other Special Challenge but that is unlocked by completing one of the later Tanner missions.